# Remove Decimal Point in a Dataframe with both Numbers and String Using Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data Frame with about 50,000 records; and I noticed that ".0" have been added behind all numbers in a column. I have been trying to remove the ".0", so that the table below;

```
N  | Movies              
1  | Save the Last Dance 
2  | Love and Other Drugs
3  | Dance with Me      
4  | Love Actually       
5  | High School Musical
6  | 2012.0      <-----
7  | Iron Man     
8  | 300.0       <-----
9  | Inception      
10 | 360.0       <-----
11 | Pulp Fiction
```

Will look like this;

```
N  | Movies              
1  | Save the Last Dance 
2  | Love and Other Drugs
3  | Dance with Me      
4  | Love Actually       
5  | High School Musical
6  | 2012     <-----
7  | Iron Man     
8  | 300      <-----
9  | Inception      
10 | 360      <----- 
11 | Pulp Fiction
```

The challenge is that the column contains both numbers and strings.

Is this possible, if yes, how?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you say number do you know if the number is actually a string or is it a float in reality? If it is a string then my answer will work, otherwise it could just be a display issue because even if stores a float, it will output to whatever the output format settings are

Comment: Can you post the line where you read the data? (e.g. `pd.read_table/pd.read_csv` or similar)

Comment: @EdChum sorry just seeing this. Still figuring out stackoverflow. By upvote, you mean the upward arrow beside your response, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a function and apply to whole column:

```
In [94]:

df = pd.DataFrame({'Movies':['Save the last dance', '2012.0']})
df
Out[94]:
                Movies
0  Save the last dance
1               2012.0

[2 rows x 1 columns]

In [95]:

def trim_fraction(text):
    if '.0' in text:
        return text[:text.rfind('.0')]
    return text

df.Movies = df.Movies.apply(trim_fraction)

In [96]:

df
Out[96]:
                Movies
0  Save the last dance
1                 2012

[2 rows x 1 columns]
```

Comment: is it possible to `.apply(trim_fraction)` to multiple columns at one time?

Comment: @As3adTintin yes something like `df[list_cols].apply(trim_fraction)` would work

Comment: thanks for responding. It doesn't seem to be working for me, i must be amiss. You are suggesting something along the lines of: `df['a', 'b', 'c'] = df['a', 'b', 'c'].apply(trim_fraction)`? yes?

Comment: @As3adTintin No you need to pass a real list: `df[['a', 'b', 'c']] = df[['a', 'b', 'c']].apply(trim_fraction)` note the double square brackets what you tried was to pass a tuple with 3 elements

Comment: I made a sample dataframe and this is not working for me. Maybe it's a problem that I'm on 2.7?

Comment: @As3adTintin You'll need to post real code as it depends, thinking about it would be easier instead to do `df[['A','B','C']] = df[['A','B','C']].apply(lambda x: x.str.replace('.0', ''))` if using a newer version of pandas

Answer (score 0):

Here is hint for you ,

In case of Valid number ,

```
a="2012.0"
try:
    a=float(a)
    a=int(a)
    print a

except:
    print a
```

Output:

```
2012
```

In case of String like "Dance with Me"

```
a="Dance with Me"
try:
    a=float(a)
    a=int(a)
    print a

except:
    print a
```

Output:

```
Dance with Me
```

Comment: Hi Fledging, 

Thank you very much for your response. 

The challenge with this is that I have about 50,000 records in the dataframe. 

Also, when I tried to do this for the whole records in the column using;
movies_v2 = int(movies[["N", "Movies"]])

I got the error:
TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'DataFrame'.

I am looking for a way to search through the whole record and replace ".0" with nothing (""). So that any value in the column with say, 456.0 will change to 456.

Thanks you.

Answer (score 0):

```
Python 2.7.2+ (default, Jul 20 2012, 22:15:08) 
[GCC 4.6.1] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> str1 = "300.0"
>>> str(int(float(str1)))
'300'
>>>
```

Comment: `float('Iron Man')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: could not convert string to float: Iron Man`